# How to understand variadic templates in c++11

Tags: templates, c++11, variadic-templates

Sometimes we use（. . .）to indicate that a template or function parameter represents a pack.
Sometimes we get an pack expansion by putting (. . . ) to the right of the pattern.

I am a little confused about this two occasions above.

In C++ standard document（14.5.3 item 4）:

> "In a function parameter pack (8.3.5); the pattern is the
>   parameter-declaration without the ellipsis."

there’s one example about this quote:

```
template<typename ...T1>
void  f1(T1 ...t1)
{
}
```

According to above description,for function parameter pack,the pattern is (T1 t1). So why can't i do somethig like that, i put (...) to the right of the pattern,then i can get the code below:

```
template<typename ...T2>
void  f2(T2 ...t2...) // f2(T2 ...t2...) -> f2((T2 ...t2)...)->f2((T2 t2)...)
{
}
```

I confusedly think that the (...) after t2 could mean pack expansion which the the pattern is (T2 t2).Then i found the code compiled success in my vs2013.Wow, do I find some inspiration yet?

I brazenly began a new attempt.

There’s another quote in C++ standard(14.5.3 item 4):

> "In a template parameter pack that is a pack expansion (14.1): — if
>   the template parameter pack is a parameter-declaration; the pattern is
>   the parameter-declaration without the ellipsis;"

```
template<typename ...T3>
void  f1(T3 ...t3)
{
}
```

According to description, for the template parameter T3, the pattern is (typename T3), so:

```
template<typename ...T4...> 
class get_a_error; // template<(typename ...T4)...> -> template<(typename T4)...>
```

Without (...) the pattern is (typename T4),so i put (...) to the right of the pattern,then i got an error.

Finally,I fell into confusion.

Comment: That second `...` in `f2` is being taken as C-style varargs. That parse is obviously not available in your last case.

Comment: I am still confused about this two occasions of（...）